# lubridating a character string

Tags: r, posixct, lubridate

I want to transform  character vectors to  POSIXct objects but having trouble achieving this

```
03-Jun-2012 5:00am PDT
```

I can use the lubridate `dmy` function for date but am having trouble combining it with time

Comment: Why not use the `as.POSIXct` function?  `as.POSIXct('03-Jun-2012 5:00am PDT', format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M%p')`

Comment: @Justin. thanks. Not sure this handles am/pm. The above suggestion with 5.00pm gives the same output. As does omitting %p

Comment: `?strptime`:  %p is used with %I (that's a cap-i) ... not with %H.

Comment: my bad! good point @DWin.  `as.POSIXct..., format='%d-%b-%Y %l:%M%p')`

Comment: looks good. thanks guys. do you want to write as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `lubridate` for this case.  Instead use the base `as.POSIXct` function:

```
as.POSIXct('03-Jun-2012 5:00am PDT', format='%d-%b-%Y %l:%M%p')
```